# Calculating Mean value with R

Tags: r, mean, montecarlo

I am trying to calculate the mean of a random variable using R, with the help of the Monte-Carlo-Simulation method, so I wrote this function:

```
> example <- function(n,B=10000) mean(replicate(B,all(sample(n):1:n)))
> set.seed(0)
> example(3)
```

Calculated with other programs this should give a value near 2.6662, but in R I keep getting this output:

```
[1] 1
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Comment: There are some errors in the code. Use of `all` is not clear there as it for logical operations. The use of `replicate` is not necessary if you are looking for a single value output. May be you need to clarify your aim a little further.

Comment: i used replicate because this is the concept of the Monte-Carlo-Simulation, to simplify it, it's just taking the mean of a large quantity of data (here 10000 samples of n) to be as accurate as possible (because taking the mean of only 10 samples for example would not be as accurate), replicate is to generate those 10000 samples.

Comment: @Manuel Which result do you expect from `all(sample(n):1:n)`?

Comment: Is there any randomness in your code? Why would your function (with argument value set to 3?) return 2.6662?

Answer (score 0):

May be what you want is the second section of the following code. Please note the use of seed, sample function etc in them. You aren't using them correctly.

```
set.seed(42)
example <- function(n,B=10000) mean(sample(1:n, n*B, replace = TRUE))
example(3)

set.seed(42)
example <- function(n,B=10000) mean(replicate(B, 
                                 sample(1:n, n, replace = TRUE)))
example(3)
```

Comment: this seems to work, but doesn't output the right values i'm looking for

Comment: In above cases, it sample 3 values from {1, 2, 3}, does this B times, and give the mean. The values has to be around 2.
From what distribution did you think you were sampling from when you were expecting 2.6662?